# Ajax - Php - Database

Tags: php, ajax

I tried a lot but don't know why or were i am making mistake , please have a look at the code below , please help.

Form Name : ajax.php

When click on key field it call the do_ajax() function , when try to retrive value in php not getting the value

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function do_ajax() {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                data=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("brand")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?brand="+document.getElementById('brand').value,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $temp = $_GET["brand"];
      echo $temp;
    ?>
    <form name="aa" method="post" action="abc.php">
      <input type="text" id="brand" name="brand" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="key" name="key" value="" onclick="do_ajax();" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <div id="aa"><b><?php echo "Heloooo" . $temp;?></b></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And code highlight shows you what is wrong.

Comment: Check syntax in  xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?   brand="+document.getElementById('brand').value,true);

Comment: sasi cant make out what is wrong in that syntax , can you please let me know